# How to generate private public key in JAVA using no external libraries

Tags: java, encryption-asymmetric

We have been given an assignment part of which requires us to generate a public private key pair. These do not need to be particularly secure, as it is just for demonstration of the concept.

**We can not use any sort of cryptography libraries or external tools.**

How would I go about generating these?

Edit: Found a pretty nice explanation of RSA here: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-rsa-algorithm

Comment: As asymmetrical cryptography via public and private keys base  on a mathematical problem (prime factorization of large prime numbers) you might want to have a look on this repository (found it by accident, there should exist many like this): https://github.com/eduardolundgren/rsa-prime-factorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use JShell to demonstrate the basic public-private key generation just using Java's `BigInteger`:

```
jshell> import java.math.BigInteger;
jshell> var rnd = new java.security.SecureRandom();
rnd ==> Hash_DRBG,SHA-256,128,reseed_only
```

First we need 2 primes

```
jshell> var p1 = BigInteger.probablePrime(512, rnd);
p1 ==> 1176110601168217581401499298469596353224364190716 ... 72507270343325790065694831

jshell> var p2 = BigInteger.probablePrime(512, rnd);
p2 ==> 1001341560055006431459083188828513502474297271020 ... 34378293673605844490263567
```

Next we calculate the public key. 0x10001 is a common exponent for the public key.

```
jshell> var n = p1.multiply(p2);
n ==> 1177688424171014462551464978852125044384293220079 ... 24824881562893076179522177

jshell> var e = BigInteger.valueOf(0x10001);
e ==> 65537
```

The public key is `e` and `n`.
Now the private part.

```
jshell> var phi = p1.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(p2.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
phi ==> 1177688424171014462551464978852125044384293220079 ... 17939317545961441623563780

jshell> var d = e.modInverse(phi);
d ==> 7023685818262702180949167670691999860354377649273 ... 38390163809778429090416313
```

The private key is now `d` and `n`.
Let's test it:

```
jshell> var secret = BigInteger.valueOf(1337);
secret ==> 1337

jshell> var enc = secret.modPow(e, n);
enc ==> 1059982071031392497566614763259148320406936402012 ... 39171914529632475117049800

jshell> enc.modPow(d, n);
$11 ==> 1337
```

We could send `enc` over the wire, and nobody could decrypt it without the knowledge of the private key. Well, at least in theory. In practice, you should pad your messages.

Comment: Thank you very much. BTW can you elaborate a bit on the common exponent part? I am a bit confused about the BigInteger.valueOf(0x10001)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65,537#Applications